# Tags in spoilers on Meta Stack Overflow are always visible

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, spoilers

Problem:

> Tags in spoilers are always visible, even if you don't put your mouse on the spoiler.

This has been an [old bug since 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230533/295232), but it was finally fixed in May this year. However, it's still a problem on Meta Stack Overflow (but not on other sites, as far as I can tell).

Here is a live demo, until the fix is live:

> [please-fix-this-here-as-well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/please-fix-this-here-as-well)

For reference, this is how it looks like at the moment of posting (without hovering over the spoiler):

[image]

Comment: Strangely the mobile view hides it successfully...

Comment: @JonClements IIRC, that has always been the case (on other sites as well).

Comment: Out of curiosity... what do we need spoiler tags for in SO?

Comment: It's something that works across all sites, so it should work here as well to satisfy my OCD.</s>

Comment: >! [nobody-cares-enough-to-fix]

Comment: >! spoilers don't work in comments :P

Comment: @yivi questions with bug tags are aggregated across sites. The question is just fine here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work fine everywhere now (in the next build, to be precise). The spoiler CSS was created back in 2010 when you didn't have a lot of flexibility in how to implement this kind of thing. Alas, it's 2017 now, so I updated it to prevent these issues from happening again (yeah I know, famous last words).